# Node.js waiting for postgres to respond to client request

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I'm building a REST API using Node.js with Express and pg installed, with a PostgreSQL database running locally. I understand the asynchronous nature of JavaScript, but what I'm not sure about it the validity of the method by which I'm responding to a request. Take a peek at my code here:

```
/* index.js */
territoryService.initTerritoryService();

var http = require("http")
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);

app.get("/nearby", function(req, res){
  var lat, lng;
  lat = parseFloat(req.query.lat);
  lng = parseFloat(req.query.lng);
  var respObj = territoryService.getNearbyTerritory(lat, lng, res);
});
```

```
/* territoryService.js */
module.exports = {
  initTerritoryService: function(){
    territoryDao = require("../dao/territoryDao.js");
    territoryDao.initTerritoryDao();
    console.log("Territory Service instantiated");
  },

  getNearbyTerritory(lat, lng, res){
    var dbRes = territoryDao.getNearbyTerritory(lat, lng, res);
    return dbRes;
  }
};
```

```
/* territoryDao.js */  
module.exports = {
  initTerritoryDao: function(){
    pg = require('pg');
    async = require('async');
    client = new pg.Client();
    var connectionString = 'postgres://username:password@localhost/table';
    pg.connect(connectionString, function (err, client, done) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Database connected");
    });
    console.log("Territory DAO instantiated");
  },

  getNearbyTerritory: function(lat, lng, res){
    var queue = [];
    queue.push(client.query.bind(client, 'SELECT * FROM territories WHERE id=39321797'));
    async.series(queue, function (err, results) {
      res.send(results);
    });
  }
};
```

Is the way I pass `res` down from the initial route through which the request was made legitimate, or is it bad practice? I'm doing so in order to respond upon pg query completion, as the call is async.

Comment: Looks like somebody's nightmare. Here's a good starting point: [Designing a RESTful API With Node and Postgres](http://mherman.org/blog/2016/03/13/designing-a-restful-api-with-node-and-postgres/).

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the direction.